# ng-repeat inside a script template not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following script template that I use to display a modal dialog inside a div element.

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Export a Table</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h3>Select Entity</h3>
      <select id="selected-entity" >
        <option ng-repeat="num in entities" value={{num}}></option>
      </select >
      <h3>Select Environment</h3>
      <select id="selected-environment">
        <option ng-repeat="e in envs" value={{e}}></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </script>

  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Create</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Export</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Import</button>
</div>
```

When I perform a `console.log` on the two objects (entities, and envs) for which I am calling `ng-repeat`, I am able to successfully log their contents to the console. Their content, however, is not displayed in the modal dialog that I pop up.

I'm new to Angular and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: we definitely need more information to help you, the best way to get help is to create a plunkr or jsFiddle. This html snippet is not enough information to help diagnose your issue.

Comment: You should never use `ng-repeat` on `<option>` elements, you instead should use `ng-options` on the `<select>` element: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: How are you compiling the template?

Comment: @dave while ng-options is preferred saying never to repeat is disingenuous. There are several use cases for using ng-repeat, they just are not commonly found. Options will be more performant though and in this case they are not needed.

Comment: @NeilS Here is my plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/vN5wJLWPBSiVoJF9XVdO?p=preview

Comment: @dave Switched from ng-repeat to ng-options and the problem still persists. I have use cases were ng-repeat works as I intend it to on an <option> element as well. So, although it might not be stylistically (or even functionally prefered to use ng-repeat), it has worked on other option elements before and I don't think the problem is related to my usage of it.

Comment: you need an `ng-model` on your `select` else it won't work

Comment: Thanks @DarrenIt worked when I used ng-options and ng-model on my element.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use ngOptions to achieve this, but if you still want to do it with ng-repeat then see the following plunker.

```
<select>
   <option ng-repeat="e in envs">{{e}}</option>
</select>
```

Please follow the plunker link for code.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DQg4NsZgVjZIaymMc3de?p=preview)